# Installing just Pages 09 from old iWork 09 Disk on Yosemite

Tags: macos, pages, iwork

I still love the old pages '09 I run it side-by side with the new pages on my two iMacs. However, on my new Macbook it is not installed and I want to run it on there (the new pages doesn't have some of the power features I need).

I have an old iWork '09 disk, and I could install the programs on there, but if I did that it would add the old numbers and keynote too. I really don't want those programs because the current numbers and keynote are fine for me. I just want to somehow extract the pages 09 install data from the CD and do an install without adding the numbers and keynote.

Is this possible, if so how. And if not, is there a way to get pages 09 on my Yosemite - running laptop without the CD?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to install it all, and then delete Numbers and Keynote from the iWork 09 folder.

For a brief time, I believe Pages 09 was offered in the Mac app store as a stand-alone program.  If you have that version on an old backup, that would be one other option.  The disc installer cannot be easily modified; and, it puts several files in **/Library/Application Support/** and maybe other locations so copying just the Pages.app from your other computer is not a viable option.